# Can't use WithContext(ctx) method on *gorm.db instead of gorm.db

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-context

I initialize my db as a struct

```
type DBStorage struct {
   db *gorm.DB
}
```

with

```
db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", DatabaseURL)
...
return &DBStorage{
   db: db,
}
```

Everything works fine: queries, updates, and all other operations. But then I tried to add Contexts to my project it didn't work like that:

```
func (dbStorage DBStorage) PutOrder(order service.Order, ctx context.Context) error {
...
   dbStorage.db.WithContext(ctx).Create(&order)
...
}
```

It says that WithContext is an unresolved reference. While `dbStorage.db.Create(&order)` works fine. How should I fix this?

I tried some silly things like removing * from the struct, but it kinda breaks the whole incapsulation idea. Also tried reading https://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html but didn't get how to implement it and if it is a solution for my case. If it is, I ask for some clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your import statement. It should be `import gorm.io/gorm` instead of `import github.com/jinzhu/gorm`.

The first version of the library is [`github.com/jinzhu/gorm`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jinzhu/gorm) where the [`gorm.DB`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB) type has no `WithContext()` method.

GORM V2 moved to https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm and has import path [`gorm.io/gorm`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm). Version 2 added the [`DB.WithContext()`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.WithContext) method.

Comment: Aaah, that's so ridiculous. I've already changed it to "gorm.io/gorm" in the script with access db funcs, forgot to change it where I initialize the db. 
thx